# Rx framework for a web crawler

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I found that Rx framework looks really useful for async operations but i cannt understand how can i use it for download a lot of pages.

i am trying write something like this

```
var en = Enumerable.Range(0,100).Select(x => WebRequest.Create("http://google.com")).Select(x => Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(x.BeginGetResponse, 
    x.EndGetResponse)().Subscribe(r => Console.WriteLine(r.ContentLength)) ).ToList();
```

Ofcourse it doesnt work. How to do it right?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What's the actual scenario? Rx may not be the right approach - the Task Parallel Library is probably enough.

Comment: @yamen In this example i just trying to download 100 pages asynchronously. I asked question about using TPL for this task and someone explain me that tpl is good for CPU bound operations. For I\O operations async methods is better. Well Rx makes working with async methods easy, right? Ofcourse i can do it without Rx but i want to learn something new.

Comment: Reasonable - is VS 11 or .NET 4.5 an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Modified to provide simple error handling.

Here's what you need to do:

```
var urls = new[]
        {
            "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693617/"
                    + "rx-framework-for-a-web-crawler",
            "http://stackoverflow.com/",
            "http://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity",
        };

Func<string, IObservable<WebResponse>> create =
    url =>
        Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            var wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
            return
                Observable
                    .FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(
                        wr.BeginGetResponse,
                        wr.EndGetResponse)
                    .Invoke()
                    .Catch(Observable.Return<WebResponse>(null));
        });

var query =
    from u in urls.ToObservable()
    from r in create(u)
    select new
    {
        URL = u,
        ContentLength = r == null ? -1L : r.ContentLength,
    };

ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;

query.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

I would be more inclined to provide better error handling than this though. I'd send out a tuple that includes the exception rather than just a `null` value.

Comment: Thanks. But if i have an exception(like 404) Subscribe just stopped work. How can i pretend it?